# How to select table column in the add button event?

Tags: java, swing

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B3CuRPd4MLwbSVdhZnFNMHN5SUE/edit?usp=sharing

I have 2 columns in jtable. If  I  typed data in each column and click somewhere else  inside the table or use the  tab button, then only  the typed data will be fixed in that column so that I can transfer it to the jTextfield on the lower side of the form by pressing the add button.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B3CuRPd4MLwbR3hjd1p0cHpGWHc/edit?usp=sharing

In the above given image, the second column value can’t be added to the text field below, as the focus is in that column. It will return a nullpointr exception.  In this case focus loss events won’t help us in achieving what I want.

I expect expert replies on how to solve this error.

Answer (score 1):

At the second image you edit cell of your `JTable`, for saving and getting that value by button click or somthing else action you can add next code before getting value:

```
TableCellEditor cellEditor = table.getCellEditor(); 
if(cellEditor != null){
    cellEditor.stopCellEditing();
}
```

where `table` is your `JTable`.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [Table Stop Editing](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/12/12/table-stop-editing/) for a couple of solutions. One way will save the data when:

1. the table loses focus
2. a specific button is clicked